# How to change JavaFX TabPane pane type

Tags: java, javafx, webview, tabpanel

I want to make a WebView inside an AnchorPane controlled by the TabPane:
[image]

Here's the TabPane hierarchy in this:

[image]

I don't know how to make a WebView fill the entire area, and be responsive at the same time. I can change the preferred size, but I don't know how to make it 100% fill the pane. I'm brand new to JavaFX, and I am using the Scene Builder (I came from Swing). Thank you!

Comment: Why not just put the web view directly in the tab?

Comment: @James_D the WebView can only be set to specific size, but I want it to fill the entire tab

Comment: What do you mean "The WebView can only be set to specific size"? Just put it directly in the tab, without using an anchor pane, and leave all the sizes at their default values.

Comment: @James_D Then it won't fill the whole pane. It will only be set to the preferred size - I need it to fill its parent

Comment: No, seriously, I tried it. The tab stretches its content node to all the available space, regardless of preferred size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tab will size its content node to fill all the available space in the tab (up to its max size). So as long as you leave the max width and max height of a web view as their defaults (`Double.MAX_VALUE`), you can simply place the web view directly in the tab without using an anchor pane, and it will be sized to the full size of the tab.

Here is a simple example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>


<TabPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <tabs>
      <Tab text="Untitled Tab">
         <content>
            <WebView fx:id="webView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
         </content>
      </Tab>
   </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Here is the document hierarchy in Scene Builder:

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry. I kept thinking I had to put it in the AnchorPane for some reason :P